# Linear Programming (LP) with large number of variables and the similar LP with small number of variables

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Assume we are given a Linear Programming (LP) where the number of variables depends on the $N$. This LP can be solved using a LP solver for small N's (e.g., 2,3,4) and has this property that the results for all of these cases follow a similar pattern and similar cost which can be used to guess the solution of the LP for other values of N. For large values of N, assuming that it follows the same pattern,  we can guess a solution for the LP (which I believe is actually the optimal solution of LP). My question is that, how can we check that this solution is optimal? Is there any technique?

Comment: You shoud recall that LP means "Linear Programing"

Comment: @JeanMarie I didn't get what you mean.

Comment: That acronyms are difficult to understand unless you recall what thy mean...

Comment: @JeanMarie Oh, okay. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all you need to do is check the reduced costs of your solution. For a maximization (minimization) problem, if they are all be negative (positive), the solution is optimal.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. What do you mean by reduced costs?

Comment: Are you familiar with the simplex algorithm?

Comment: No, I have an optimization course this semester and I will learn it soon. Thanks. Just to recheck, you mean if I have a guess, I can consider that as input for a simplex algorithm. Then, if the reduced cost is positive (for a minimization problem), the guess is optimal? Is this checking something that can be done manually for even large N?

Comment: You are correct, you can put the solution as an input for the simplex algorithm and manually check the reduced costs. The number of reduced costs you have to check equals the number of constraints. Obviously this can become a little boring to do if there are many.

Comment: Thanks. I know there are a lot of materials on simplex algorithm, but can you please introduce one to me so that I can read it?

Comment: I meant, I took a look at some of the materials. Most of them try to solve the LP by finding the Simplex tableau and then finding a pivot ... So they proposed an approach for that. But, I don't see where I can input my guess as the initial point.